# user validation doesnt work after OnMenuItemClick event

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback, aspmenu-control

I have a web form which includes 2 different panels in `.net 2008. .net framework version is 3.5`. Each panel includes user input controls like textbox, dropdownlist. I have an asp menu control for navigation. First item is selected at the beginning. When the user clicks the button, if the user doesn’t fill the required user controls, validation control fires. But when I click the other aspmenuitem, then click the button without filling the required user controls, user validation does not fire.

Could you help me about why this situation takes place?

[image description 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XY61.jpg)

[image description 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSz6z.jpg)

Comment: Share your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

OnMenuItemClick="menuTab_MenuItemClick" BackColor="#F7F6F3" 
             DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" align="center" 
             ForeColor="#7C6F57" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" >

```
         <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
         <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
         <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
         <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px"  />

         <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
         <Items> 
          <asp:MenuItem  Text="Nakit İşlem Sorgu(07.08.2015 ve sonrası)"    Value="0"></asp:MenuItem> 
         <asp:MenuItem  Text="Arşiv Kartsız İşlem Sorgu(07.08.2015 öncesi)" Value="1"   ></asp:MenuItem> 


         </Items> 
         <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="#cccccc" ForeColor="#333333"  
             HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" /> 
         <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White"  /> 
     </asp:Menu>
```